# Migration from Couchdb to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, couchdb, logstash

I want to migrate my multi-database CouchDB(Cloudant) server to ElasticSearch 2.x. Currently I can sync a CouchDB database to my ElasticSearch server with Logstash couch_changes plugin. The problem is the architecture. Is it possible to design a similar architecture like CouchDB on ElasticSearch, where I can create separate databases or database like containers for my tenants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analogy is different on Elasticsearch. But you can roughly think of elasticsearch indices as databases in other RDMSs.

Check: https://www.elastic.co/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index

```
MySQL => Databases => Tables => Columns/Rows
Elasticsearch => Indices => Types => Documents with Properties
```

You can create multiple indices.

Comment: Thanks Alper. It will definitely help me with this purpose. Is there any other approach for synchronizing CouchDB with Elasticsearch that you can think of?